# Rain drops not rendering in rendered animation but appear in viewport

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, particles

So, i just followed a Tutorial on youtube to make rain. It works all good, viewport is perfect, animation too but once i render it... Its simply not there. The "Show Emitter" box is checked, i tried everything and looked everywhere but i can't seem find any answers that solve my problem.i've been looking for hours now in blender and can't find the problem. Is it a bug? did i do something wrong? Idk but can someone help me please, im new to blender.

Comment: Hello, could you please share the emitter and the particle object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: There is my full scene: https://pasteall.org/media/0/7/077714af67c50d2fcf6ed4a53730e905.blend

Comment: In viewport everything looks okay but i noticed that once i start to render the animation, the rain drops dont fall, they stay on the circle or in mid air but never reach the umbrella.

Comment: weird, it's seems to work here, this is what i get: https://zupimages.net/up/22/07/e2po.jpg

Comment: Yeah so i just tried to render the image and its perfectly fine, the animation however doesn't want to do it...

Comment: Rendering it into multiple PNGs instead of FFmpeg format doesn't work either.

Comment: you're right, that said if you bake the emission it will work, please try, it may be just that

Comment: how can you do that? Im really new to blender, i don't know the ins and outs of this program.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Particle System* panel, choose the end frame and under *Cache*, press on *Bake*, it will pre-calculate the particle emission and the render should correctly work. It's generally better to bake a particle emission or a physic simulation before rendering:

[image]

Comment: YEEEEES! Thank you a lot! finallyyyyyyyy !!!